# UITABLEView duplicate rows issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I cannot resolve this issue and I have no idea why my UITableView duplicates rows whenever I click on the segment control. I want to refresh the table view with new data when segment control changes. I have tried many things and googled it but could not find any solution. I would appreciated if someone can help me please. I am still learning xcode and a lot to learn. here is my code -

```
#import "citsViewController.h"
#import "citsParseOperation.h"
#import "citsFuelFinder.h"
#import "citsTableViewCell.h"
#import "citsAboutViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

// this framework is imported so we can use the kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet error code
#import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface citsViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
    NSString *currentLoc;
    int productName;

}

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *earthquakeList;
@property (nonatomic) citsFuelFinder *currentEarthquakeObject;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *locationLabel;

// queue that manages our NSOperation for parsing earthquake data
@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *parseQueue;

@end


#pragma mark -

@implementation citsViewController
@synthesize nomatchesView;
@synthesize footerLabel;
@synthesize headerLabel;
@synthesize fuelType;
@synthesize bannerIsVisible;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    //refresh the tableview
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl=[[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];

    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl=refreshControl;

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aboutUs:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //add info button in the navigation controller
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton] ;

    //initialize location manager
    locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    //to get location
    geocoder=[[CLGeocoder alloc] init];


    //show network activity
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    //call the location manager update function
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}



-(void)refresh:(id)sender {

       //update table data
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}




- (void)dealloc {

    // we are no longer interested in these notifications:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:kAddEarthquakesNotificationName
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:kEarthquakesErrorNotificationName
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

/**
 Handle errors in the download by showing an alert to the user. This is a very simple way of handling the error, partly because this application does not have any offline functionality for the user. Most real applications should handle the error in a less obtrusive way and provide offline functionality to the user.
 */
- (void)handleError:(NSError *)error {

    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
    NSString *alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Title for alert displayed when download or parse error occurs.");
    NSString *okTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"OK ", @"OK Title for alert displayed when download or parse error occurs.");

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:errorMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:okTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}

/**
 Our NSNotification callback from the running NSOperation to add the earthquakes
 */
- (void)addEarthquakes:(NSNotification *)notif {

    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    [self addEarthquakesToList:[[notif userInfo] valueForKey:kEarthquakeResultsKey]];

}


/**
 Our NSNotification callback from the running NSOperation when a parsing error has occurred
 */
- (void)earthquakesError:(NSNotification *)notif {

    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    [self handleError:[[notif userInfo] valueForKey:kEarthquakesMessageErrorKey]];
}

/**
 The NSOperation "ParseOperation" calls addEarthquakes: via NSNotification, on the main thread which in turn calls this method, with batches of parsed objects. The batch size is set via the kSizeOfFuelPumpBatch constant.
 */
- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes {


    NSInteger startingRow = [self.earthquakeList count];
    NSInteger earthquakeCount = [earthquakes count];

    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:earthquakeCount];



    for (NSInteger row = startingRow; row < (startingRow+earthquakeCount); row++) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
    NSLog(@"record count %d",earthquakeCount);

   [self.earthquakeList addObjectsFromArray:earthquakes];

  [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];

}




#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

// The number of rows is equal to the number of earthquakes in the array.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


        return [self.earthquakeList count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kEarthquakeCellID = @"EarthquakeCellID";
    citsTableViewCell *cell = (citsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEarthquakeCellID];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[citsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kEarthquakeCellID];

    }


    // Get the specific earthquake for this row.
    citsFuelFinder *earthquake = (self.earthquakeList)[indexPath.row];

        [cell configureWithEarthquake:earthquake];


    return cell;
}

/**
 * When the user taps a row in the table, display the USGS web page that displays details of the earthquake they selected.
 */
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *buttonTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel");
    //NSString *buttonTitle1 = NSLocalizedString(@"Show USGS Site in Safari", @"Show USGS Site in Safari");
    NSString *buttonTitle2 = NSLocalizedString(@"Show Location in Maps", @"Show Location in Maps");

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:buttonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles: buttonTitle2, nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}


-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 500)];
    headerLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 1.0, 300, 25)];
    headerLabel.numberOfLines=0;
    fuelType=[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ULP", @"PULP",@"Diesel",@"LPG", nil]];
    fuelType.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 300,25);
    //set first segment selected
    [fuelType setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
    [fuelType addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHasChangedValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    headerLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];

    [headerView insertSubview:fuelType aboveSubview:headerLabel];

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footer.gif"]]];
    return headerView;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 60;
}


#pragma mark -

/**
 * Called when the user selects an option in the sheet. The sheet will automatically be dismissed.
 */
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    citsFuelFinder *earthquake = (citsFuelFinder *)(self.earthquakeList)[selectedIndexPath.row];

    switch (buttonIndex) {

        case 0: {
            // open the earthquake info in Maps

            // create a map region pointing to the earthquake location
            CLLocationCoordinate2D location = (CLLocationCoordinate2D) { earthquake.latitude, earthquake.longitude };
            NSValue *locationValue = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:location];

            MKCoordinateSpan span = (MKCoordinateSpan) { 2.0, 2.0 };
            NSValue *spanValue = [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:span];

            NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{ MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey : @(MKMapTypeStandard),
                                            MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey : locationValue,
                                            MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey : spanValue,
                                            MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey : @(NO),
                                             MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving : @(NO) };

            // make sure the map item has a pin placed on it with the title as the earthquake location
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
            [mapItem setName:earthquake.location];
            [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

            break;
        }
    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:YES];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    // Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"updating data";
    HUD.square = YES;

    self.earthquakeList = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.currentEarthquakeObject=nil;

if([self.earthquakeList count] >0)
{
    [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

    // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(addEarthquakesToList:) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];


    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;


     if (currentLocation != nil) {
         NSString *latitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
         NSString *longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

         citsTableViewCell *tcell = [[citsTableViewCell alloc] init];
         //set the latitude and longitude
         tcell.lon =[longitude doubleValue];
         tcell.lat = [latitude doubleValue];


         NSLog(@"Lat:%@, Lon:%@", latitude,latitude);
     }




    //stop updating location
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];


    //reverse geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

            currentLoc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placemark.locality];
            if(currentLoc == NULL)
            {
               currentLoc=@"N/A";
            }


            NSLog(@"%@",currentLoc);


            //add text to headertext
            NSDate *currDate=[NSDate date];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"];

            NSString *dateString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
            NSString *loc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your location: %@, Updated on: %@", currentLoc, dateString ];


            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy"];

            NSString *headerDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
            headerLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Prices for: %@\n%@", headerDate,loc];


    //currentLoc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemark.locality];
    currentLoc=@"Mirrabooka";

            if(productName==0)
            {
                productName=1;
            }
    NSString *prdStr=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", productName];

    NSString *str =[currentLoc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

    NSString *feedURLString =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://www.fuelwatch.wa.gov.au/fuelwatch/fuelWatchRSS?Product=%@&Suburb=%@", prdStr,str ];
    NSURLRequest *earthquakeURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:feedURLString]];

            NSLog(@"%@",feedURLString);
    // send the async request (note that the completion block will be called on the main thread)
    //
    // note: using the block-based "sendAsynchronousRequest" is preferred, and useful for
    // small data transfers that are likely to succeed. If you doing large data transfers,
    // consider using the NSURLConnectionDelegate-based APIs.
    //
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:earthquakeURLRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               // back on the main thread, check for errors, if no errors start the parsing
                               //
                               [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


                               // here we check for any returned NSError from the server, "and" we also check for any http response errors
                               if (error != nil) {
                                   [self handleError:error];
                               }
                               else {


                                   // check for any response errors
                                   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                   if ((([httpResponse statusCode]/100) == 2) ) {


                                       // Update the UI and start parsing the data,
                                       // Spawn an NSOperation to parse the earthquake data so that the UI is not
                                       // blocked while the application parses the XML data.
                                       //
                                       citsParseOperation *parseOperation = [[citsParseOperation alloc] initWithData:data];
                                       [self.parseQueue addOperation:parseOperation];


                                   }
                                   else {
                                       NSString *errorString =
                                       NSLocalizedString(@"HTTP Error", @"Error message displayed when receving a connection error.");
                                       NSDictionary *userInfo = @{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : errorString};
                                       NSError *reportError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"HTTP"
                                                                                  code:[httpResponse statusCode]
                                                                              userInfo:userInfo];
                                       [self handleError:reportError];
                                   }
                               }
                           }];


            // Start the status bar network activity indicator.
    // We'll turn it off when the connection finishes or experiences an error.
    //
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    self.parseQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(addEarthquakes:)
                                                 name:kAddEarthquakesNotificationName object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(earthquakesError:)
                                                 name:kEarthquakesErrorNotificationName object:nil];


        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }

    } ];

    NSLog(@"%d",[self.earthquakeList count]);


}


-(void)clearData{


    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            NSLog(@"Deleted: %d",i);
        }

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        //[self.tableView reloadData] ;

}




-(void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue{


    int product;
    product=fuelType.selectedSegmentIndex;
    switch (product) {
        case 0:

            productName=1;

            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            [self clearData];
             break;
        case 1:

            productName=2;
            [self clearData];
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

            break;
        case 2:

            productName=4;
            [self clearData];
           [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;
        case 3:
            prod![enter image description here][1]uctName=5;

          [self clearData];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

    }

    NSLog(@"%d",productName);

    return;

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all previous object from the self.earthquakeList before adding new 1. use `[self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects]`

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, I have tried - `code`- (void)addEarthquakes:(NSNotification *)notif {
    
    if(![self.earthquakeList count])
    {
    
    [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
    }
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    [self addEarthquakesToList:[[notif userInfo] valueForKey:kEarthquakeResultsKey]];
    
} but getting error

Comment: sorry i am not getting error but still it is repeating the rows again and again

Comment: @Tajuddin can you please explain repeating ?Is the items text is duplicating in the Table without increasing the actual row count or Row count is actually getting double itself as well?

Comment: increasing the number of rows, row count increasing by one every time I click on segment control even though it does not retain the old value but only the rows duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this Line,

```
[self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

And uncomment,

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

You are Already updating the data set, So you just need to reload the tableView instead of explicitly insert row.